# SVG Blur Filter not working on iOS wkwebview

Tags: cordova, vue.js, svg, svg-filters

I'm somewhat new to using SVGs and I've run into an issue where `feGaussianBlur` filter is not being rendered correctly on iOS wkwebview. It works fine on android and desktop though. I'm not sure exactly how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

I should mention that this is a cordova/vue project, and cordova is using apple wkwebview for the web view.

[Blur Working (Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXjgK.png)

[Blur Not Working (iOS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEQJs.png)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="120%" width="120%">
  <defs>
    <filter
      id="myblurfilter"
      x="0%"
      y="0%"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
    >
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" edgeMode="duplicate" result="blur" />
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="1 1" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feImage id="feimage" xlink:href="#rect2" result="mask" />
      <feComposite in2="mask" in="blur" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <rect id="rect" width="100%" height="100%" rx="5" />
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <use xlink:href="#rect" />
    </clipPath>
    <rect id="rect2" y="70%" width="100%" height="30%" fill="#fff" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" />
  <image
    x="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    filter="url(#myblurfilter)"
    clip-path="url(#clip)"
    :xlink:href="data.imageURL"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
  />
  <use opacity=".15" xlink:href="#rect2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson This is a Vue project, so the initial colon is shorthand for `v-bind`, which is used by Vue. That colon does not end up being bundled into the code.

Comment: If you declare filterUnits as userSpaceOnUse - you should probably be using those units for your filter dimensions. Chrome will overlook stuff like that but not firefox or safari (usually). feGaussianBlur has no edgeMode in SVG 1.1 -0 which is all that Safari supports. Also filters in Safari don't like to fetch references that haven't already been defined, so that rect2 may not be fetched by the feImage.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Tried your suggestions, but could not get the blur to render. Not sure if I'm completely understanding your instructions though. You did make me realize though that this isn't working in Firefox either. Perhaps you could do a quick jsfiddle to show me what exactly what you mean by your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of what I mentioned in the comment above. I also explicitly dimensioned and positioned each element (x/y/width/height) which can sometimes give problems in Safari. I also replaced the `use` in the clipPath with a paste of the shape. This *should* work.

This doesn't work in Firefox for another reason - which is that feImage doesn't support fragment references in Firefox. You have to inline any shapes you want to feed into feImage using a data:uri.

Update - version 2: for some reason iOS Safari doesn't like the feImage/rect2 combination, so I changed filter primitives to objectBoundingBox and adjusted the stdDeviation for the blur to % units and switched to using a positioned feFlood for the mask - this seems to work in iOS Safari now.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="120%" width="120%">
  <defs>
    <rect id="rect" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" rx="5" />

    <clipPath id="clip">
      <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" rx="5" />
    </clipPath>

    <rect id="rect2" x="0%" y="70%" width="100%" height="30%" fill="#fff" />

    <filter
      id="myblurfilter"
      x="0%"
      y="0%"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">

      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".005"/>
      <feComponentTransfer result="blur">
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="1 1" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feFlood flood-color="white"  x="0" y="0.7" height="0.3" width="1" result="mask"/>
      <feComposite in2="mask" in="blur" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>

  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" />
  <image
    x="0%"
    y="0%"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    filter="url(#myblurfilter)"
    clip-path="url(#clip)"
    xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/DandelionFlower.jpg"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
  />
  <use opacity=".15" xlink:href="#rect2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works on OSX safari, but not iOS safari unfortunately.

Comment: huh...now I'm interested - give me a day to figure out how to make this play on iOS